# How to use a Jinja2 extension direct from a Flask render_template

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm working on a Flask app that is working just fine, until I try to add the following line to a template to be rendered:

```
{% do totals.update({tier: 0}) %}
```

The current code for rendering the template uses Flask's `render_template()`:

```
from flask import Flask, Response, request, session
from flask import render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

..
return render_template(<template.htlm>,...)
```

This fails with with following error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'do'. Jinja was looking for the following tags: 'endfor' or 'else'. The innermost block that needs to be closed is 'for'.
```

The obvious fix is to add the `jinja2.ext.do` extension to jinja. I have been able to do so successfully using Jinja2 directly, as per:

```
from jinja2 import Environment, PackageLoader
ENV = Environment(loader=PackageLoader('ticket_app', 'templates'), extensions=['jinja2.ext.do'])
...
TEMP = ENV.get_template('div_' + div_id + '.html')
return TEMP.render(sales_new=sales_new, event_config=event_config)
```

However, I would prefer to not use Jinja2 directly... The app was only using Flask and `render_template()` before, and as `render_template()` uses Jinja2 under the hood (as far as I understand) it seems that it should be possible to make `render_template()` understand the `jinja2.ext.do` extension (or any other extension for that matter).

So far, I've tried the following:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD'] = True
app.config['EXPLAIN_TEMPLATE_LOADING'] = True
env = app.jinja_env
env.add_extension('jinja2.ext.do')
```

While the above does not throw an error, it is also not causing it to make `render_template()` understand the `jinja2.ext.do` extension.

Any suggestions? Should this be possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 5):

**Update for Flask v.2.0 :**

Since v.2.0, the below solution raise a `KeyError: 'extensions'` exception. Try [this](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/extensions/) instead.

---

For Flask v.1.1, you can directly access to the Jinja extensions loaded by Flask with the  [Flask.jinja_options](http://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Flask.jinja_options) dictionary. In your case, adding just this line should do the trick:

```py
app = Flask(__name__)
app.jinja_options['extensions'].append('jinja2.ext.do')
```

Make sure you update your Flask (using pip: `pip install -U Flask`).

Answer (score 4):

I actually found that the option that Zatiranyk outlined broke sometimes (specifically when I tried to use Flask-SocketIO.

```
app.jinja_options['extensions'].append('jinja2.ext.do')
```

The solution that I found was to use the below option instead:

```
app.jinja_env.add_extension('jinja2.ext.do')
```